# Add days to Date object and then converting to local string?

Tags: javascript

How can i add 5 days to the current date, and then convert it to a string representing the local date and time?

```
const newDate = new Date();

const test = newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 5).toLocaleString();
```

Just returns the number of milliseconds.. (same if i use `toString()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using any libraries, Vanilla JS solution:

```js
const now = new Date()
const inFiveDays = new Date(new Date(now).setDate(now.getDate() + 5))
console.log('now', now.toLocaleString())
console.log('inFiveDays', inFiveDays.toLocaleString())
```

This even works when your date overflows the current month.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is by using a date library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) or `date-fns`. I gave an example below using `date-fns` and [addDays](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/addDays)

```
const newDate = new Date();
const fiveDaysLater = addDays(newDate, 5);
```

Comment: That's exactly what i'm trying to avoid.. (using a library)

Comment: I vote for this as I cannot find a way to add days with pure JS especially for scenario when the current date is the last day of the month. The moment JS solution is the only way it increments the month along with day if current date is last day of the month

Answer (score 0):

Just use `new Date()` in front of it.

```js
const newDate = new Date();
const add  =5
const test = newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + add)
console.log(new Date(test).toLocaleString());
```